# Продлить жизнь конструктора

Tags: c++

В конструкторе инициализируются локальные переменные. Хотелось бы использовать их в других методах класса, какие есть методы решения данной проблемы?

Comment: сделать эти переменные полями, какие тут могут быть сомнения?

Comment: в полях нельзя использовать auto, а очень хочется.

Comment: Так тогда бы и спрашивали, как объявить поля класса с автоматическим выводом типа, и привели бы пример, иллюстрирующий, почему это вам понадобилось.

Comment: static меня не устраивает.

Comment: Может быть шаблоны?